# Stringstreams not working c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve UVA problem number 482 (permutation arrays), but the thing I want to ask isn't the solution, but why my stringstream in my code doesn't work as I expect them to.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string urutan,nilai,T;
float zzz;
int lalala,a;

int main()
{
    vector<int> line;
    vector<float> numbers;
    vector<float> results;
    stringstream ss1(urutan),ss2(nilai);
    getline(cin,T);
    a = atoi(T.c_str());
    while(a--)
    {
        getline(cin,urutan);
        getline(cin,nilai);
        lalala = 0;

        while(ss1 >> zzz)
        {
            line.push_back(zzz);
            lalala++;
        }
        while(ss2 >> zzz)
        {
            numbers.push_back(zzz);
        }
        results.resize(lalala);

        for (int i =0; i < lalala; i++)
        {
            results[line[i]-1] = numbers[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < lalala; i++)
        {
            cout << results[i] << endl;
        }
        numbers.clear();
        results.clear();
        line.clear();
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

as you can see, there's 2 stringstream operation on the code. But when I try to run, the code seems just skipping the stringstream and cout part!! What's the problem?

Comment: I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: You're not loading your string stream with any content. You're initializing it with an empty `std::string` *before* you actually load the string with your `getline()`. The strings loaded into a string stream aren't by reference. Load `ss1` *after* your `getline`.

Comment: Note that declaring the stringstreams right before use instead of at the very top would have prevented this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string a string stream is constructed with isn't referenced; its *copied*.  You're loading an empty string into your stream(s), then changing nothing about the **stream** when reading your data. Move the stream construction inside your loop:

```
vector<int> line;
vector<float> numbers;
vector<float> results;
stringstream ss1(urutan),ss2(nilai); // MOVE THIS
getline(cin,T);
a = atoi(T.c_str());
while(a--)
{
    getline(cin,urutan);
    getline(cin,nilai);
    lalala = 0;

    while(ss1 >> zzz)
```

To here:

```
vector<int> line;
vector<float> numbers;
vector<float> results;
getline(cin,T);
a = atoi(T.c_str());
while(a--)
{
    getline(cin,urutan);
    getline(cin,nilai);
    lalala = 0;

    stringstream ss1(urutan),ss2(nilai); // MOVED HERE
    while(ss1 >> zzz)
```

Comment: @user3022713 you're welcome. You could have even moved the input and string stream for ss2 even further down the code, but I leave that to you. This should work for now.